# how to get image true css display property

Tags: javascript, html, css, properties

i got a piece of html

```
<img style="cursor: pointer; width: auto; height: auto; display: inline;" src="http://www.kidsgen.com/fables_and_fairytales/images/rapunzel.gif" alt="rapunzel" title="rapunzel" align="right">
```

and even if i set `display: inline;` in its style, when i'm trying to get its css display property like this:

```
alert($('img:first').css('display'))
```

or

```
var el=document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0]
alert(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el,null)['display'])
```

it always gives me value `block`.

what's wrong?

Comment: Use an inspector and trace the style, maybe there is a `display: block !important` somewhere

Comment: i've just checked image styles in firebug. there are no such styles as `display: block !important` or `display: block`

Answer (score 4):

The `align='right'` property assignment is causing the img element to have its display property set to 'block'. Your code without the `align='right'` propery will alert 'inline' [on jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/rsGQ9/1/)

```
<body>
    <img style="cursor: pointer; width: auto; height: auto; display: inline;" src="http://www.kidsgen.com/fables_and_fairytales/images/rapunzel.gif" alt="rapunzel" title="rapunzel" />
</body>

alert($('img:first').css('display')); // alerts 'inline'
```

A relevant piece of extra information is img tags are in fact [inline elements by default.](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp) However, with `align='right'` set inside the img tag, I was unable to set the display property back to inline even by inserting this line of code:

```
$('img:first').css('display', 'inline');
```

Answer (score 2):

Its because you have `align="right"` in the image tag;

That CSS rule is used to align block elements ([Learn more](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp)).